# tinyint column not working while calling =0 but does =1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column of 1s and 0s when I calle the MILF = 1 its works great
but when I call MILF =0 or MILF !=1 it doesnt work what am I missing on the tinyint column?

should I change it to something else that tinyint?

WORKS

```
SELECT   `MILF`,`page`,`img`,`Name`,`item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`),
         @rank_count := @rank_count + (totalrate/nrrates < @prev_value) rank,
         @prev_value := totalrate/nrrates avg
FROM     table, (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init
WHERE MILF =1 ORDER BY avg DESC
```

DOES NOT WORK

```
    SELECT   `MILF`,`page`,`img`,`Name`,`item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`),
             @rank_count := @rank_count + (totalrate/nrrates < @prev_value) rank,
             @prev_value := totalrate/nrrates avg
    FROM     table, (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init
WHERE MILF =0 ORDER BY avg DESC
```

There is a MILF column of zeros and ones
the 0 means she is not a milf and the value was set to default
the 1 means she is a milf

the hard way would be to set the not milf value to another value different than 0 but is there a reason it doesn't work with 0?

Comment: Is it `NULL` and not 0?

Comment: No its just 0 by default

Comment: Absent a demonstration of the behavior you describe, a test case, it's not possible to help. You say you "call" **`MILF =0 or MILF !=1`**, we take that to mean this is an expression evaluated as a boolean, either in the SELECT list, as the argument to a function, or as a predicate (i.e. in a `WHERE` or `ON` clause. You say it "doesn't work"... we take that to mean either an unexpected error is being returned, or the resultset is not as you intend. One likely possibility is that this expression is actually part of a larger expression, the precedence of `AND` and `OR` operators is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, we're just guessing.

My guess is that the specific issue you are encountering is *not* really related to the `TINYINT` datatype.

My guess is that you aren't accounting for the order of precedence of the `AND` and `OR` boolean operators.

But those are just guesses.

---

You say you "call" **`MILF =0 or MILF !=1`**. We take that to mean that this is being evaulated as a boolean expression, either as an expression in the `SELECT` list, as an argument to a function, in a predicate (i.e. in the `WHERE` or `ON` clause), in the `ORDER BY` clause, or somewhere else in the statement.

You say that "it doesn't work" and that it's "not working". We take that to mean you are executing a SQL statement, and the statement is returning an unexpected error, or that the rows being returned by a SELECT statement don't meet your expectation, or you are running some other DML operation that is producing unexpected results.

---

test case, sample table, sample data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, milf TINYINT);
INSERT INTO mytable (id,milf) VALUES (10,0),(11,1),(12,2),(13,-1),(14,NULL);
```

sample query

```
SELECT id
     , milf
     , milf =1
     , milf =0
     , milf !=1
     , milf <=> NULL
  FROM mytable
 ORDER BY id
```

resultset returned:

```
    id    milf  milf =1  milf =0  milf !=1  milf <=> NULL  
------  ------  -------  -------  --------  -------------
    10       0        0        1         1              0
    11       1        1        0         0              0
    12       2        0        0         1              0
    13      -1        0        0         1              0
    14  (NULL)   (NULL)   (NULL)    (NULL)              1
```

The behavior is as defined in the MySQL Reference Manual.

Comment: there are no values of 2 or -1 there is just 0 or 1, 0 she is not a MILF or 1 she is a MILF but when i selected the 0 it gave me the results as 1